# Iterate over a column using fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have the following `df` that repeats itself in the `Day` column:

```
     Day    Value
0     0      1.0
1   NaN      1.6
2   NaN      1.0
3   NaN      1.7
4   NaN      6.0
5     0      9.0
6   NaN      7.8
7   NaN      2.5
8   NaN      1.2
9   NaN      3.4
...
```

I would like to `fillna` incrementing  `+1`  in each row. Thus getting this output:

```
    Day     Value
0     0       1.0
1     1       1.6
2     2       1.0
3     3       1.7
4     4       6.0
5     0       9.0
6     1       7.8
7     2       2.5
8     3       1.2
9     4       3.4
...
```

I tried `df.Day.fillna(value = dfs.iloc[-1]['Day] + 1, inplace = True)`

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the cumulative summation with `cumsum`.

```
df.fillna(1, inplace=True)
df['Day'] = df['Day'].groupby((df['Day']- df['Day'].shift()!=0).cumsum()).cumsum()

df
    Day Value
0   0.0 1.0
1   1.0 1.6
2   2.0 1.0
3   3.0 1.7
4   4.0 6.0
5   0.0 9.0
6   1.0 7.8
7   2.0 2.5
8   3.0 1.2
9   4.0 3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function (edit: `import numpy as np` before):

```
>>> def func(iterable):
...     counter = 1
...     out = []
...     for item in iterable:
...         if item == 0:
...             out.append(0)
...             counter = 1
...         elif np.isnan(item) == True:
...             out.append(counter)
...             counter += 1
...     return out
```

Given dataframe x:

```
>>> x
   Day
0  0.0
1  NaN
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  NaN
5  0.0
6  NaN
7  NaN
8  NaN
9  NaN
>>> x['Day'] = func(x['Day'])
>>> x
   Day
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    0
6    1
7    2
8    3
9    4
```